# Cannot remotely run a query on a Hive table in a non-default container in HDInsight

Tags: c#, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight, hcatalog

I'm trying to launch a Hive query from .NET using [Linq to Hive](http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Simple%20Linq%20To%20Hive%20Query&referringTitle=LINQ%20to%20Hive).

The challenge is that the query is supposed to run on an external table which is not in the default HDInsight container, so I've added the container's credentials to `core-site.xml` and restarted Hive's deamons.

However, I'm getting the following error:

> Container ... in account ... not found, and we can't create  it using
>   anoynomous credentials.

Here is my code:

```
var db = new MyHiveDatabase(
    new Uri("https://myclustername.azurehdinsight.net"),
    username,
    password,
    nonDefaultStorageAccount, nonDefaultStorageAcountKey);
    // I've also tried: defaultStorageAccount, defaultStorageAcountKey


var q = from x in db.ExternalTableName
        group x by x.Name
        into g
        select new {Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count()};

q.ExecuteQuery().Wait();
```

The connection succeeds and a Hive job is created (I can even see an HQL file with the query), but the Hive job writes the above-mentioned error to stderr.

I've been trying to solve this for hours, changing this and that, I've even tried `WebHCatHttpClient` instead of Linq, but to no avail... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the Hive table has been created?  I don't know the reasons, but Hive restricts creating an external table only in 'local' mode.

You can use the invoke-hive PowerShell cmdlet to run a hive query like "select count(*) from " to verify.

For more PowerShell or HDInsight .NET SDK samples, see http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/submit-hadoop-jobs-programmatically/#hive-sdk.

Comment: The table was created directly on the cluster using Remote Desktop. And selections do work this way.
Anyway, I gave up trying this and moved all the data to the default container.